# How to group and filter a dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark

Attached is my dataframe and I'm trying to find a way in pySpark to filter Link Name for which none of the Supports are with Status 'In'. For eg. The expected output should be only Link3 as none of the supports associated to it are with 'In'

| Link Name | Support | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Link1 | Support1 | In |
| Link1 | Support2 | In |
| Link1 | Support3 | Out |
| Link2 | Support4 | In |
| Link2 | Support5 | In |
| Link3 | Support6 | Out |
| Link3 | Support7 | Out |

Can someone please help me here?

The expected output should be only Link3 as none of the supports associated to it are without 'In'

Comment: Please include code as text and not as screenshot.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer I've added my table and removed the screenshot. Will you please take a look now?

Comment: Ideally you should show what you tried and where you got stuck.
IIUC, the problem can be rephrased as: 1. Filter columns with `status`==`in`, get a set of `link name`s, subtract that set from the set of all `link name`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this with window function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

inputData = [
    ("Link1", "Support1", "In"),
    ("Link1", "Support2", "In"),
    ("Link1", "Support3", "Out"),
    ("Link2", "Support4", "In"),
    ("Link2", "Support5", "In"),
    ("Link3", "Support6", "Out"),
    ("Link3", "Support7", "Out"),
]
inputDf = spark.createDataFrame(inputData, schema=["Link Name", "Support", "Status"])

window = Window.partitionBy("Link Name").orderBy(F.col("Status").asc())

dfWithRank = inputDf.withColumn("dense_rank", F.dense_rank().over(window))
dfWithRank.filter(
    (F.col("dense_rank") == F.lit(1)) & (F.col("Status") == F.lit("Out"))
).select("Link Name").distinct().show()
```

I am grouping by link name and sorting by status within group. If first status within group sorted ascending is "Out" it means that "In" status does not exists for such partition and thats what filter is checking

At the end i am selecting only Link Name and calling distinct to get just single record with Link Name

Output is

```
+---------+
|Link Name|
+---------+
|    Link3|
+---------+
```